Why does it say that the module not found when I have the python file open right next to it?
So, I have a python file called 'Multiple Animations' and anyour textother one called 'Ball'. I wanted to import my python file Ball, to my Multiple Animations one. But this is this is what my terminal window showed :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shipr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Vihaan's 
python\Multiple Animations.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Ball import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Ball'

This is what I have written in my Multiple Animations file :
from Ball import *
from tkinter import *
import time

window = Tk()

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

CANVAS = Canvas(window)
CANVAS.pack()

volleyball = Ball(CANVAS, 0, 0, 100, 1, 1, 'white')

while True:
    volleyball.move()
    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

window.mainloop()

And this is what I have written in my Ball file :
class Ball:

    def __init__(self, CANVAS, x, y, diameter, xvelocity, yvelocity, color):
        self.CANVAS = CANVAS
        self.image = CANVAS.create_oval(x, y, diameter, diameter, fill=color)
        self.xvelocity = xvelocity
        self.yvelocity = yvelocity

    def move(self):
        coordinates = self.CANVAS.coords(self.image)
        print(coordinates)

I checked if I had any naming conflicts because sometimes it solves the problem, but I didn't see any. I changed the names of some things, but it still wouldn't  work. And I only like the Pycharm community version (since I don't like paying for digital stuff).

Firstly, I think you need to make sure that both Multiple Animations and Ball are in the same directory since Python searches the same directory first. If they aren't in the same directory, you can move Ball so it's in the same directory as Multiple Animations. If Ball is in a subdirectory, the import line can be written as From .Ball import * as the . means Python will search for the Ball file within the directory of Multiple Animations.

my attempt:
Ball file :
def print_ball():
    
    print('ball')

my test_import :
import imp


ball_imp = imp.load_source('Ball' ,'Ball')


ball_imp.print_ball()

Both files in the same Folder
Output on screen running test_import with python test_import:
ball

see : Import a python module without the .py extension and  What does the first argument of the imp.load_source method do?
NOTE :

DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses

